# Check value against each value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to check if

`$price_a = 30;`

is greater than all the values in

```
$all_prices = [
    1 => 12,
    2 => 24,
    3 => 32,
    4 => 44
];
```

I guess I'd have to loop through the array and do the check for each iteration but I'm not sure how that loop should look like. Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: `foreach($all_prices as $value)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it by using max function of php :

```
<?php 
    if($price_a > max($all_prices)){
        echo "Greater than all the values";
    }
    else{
        echo "Smaller than ".max($all_prices);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to find out **which** of the values in the array is actually smaller than `$price_a`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the max function in array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

`echo max(2, 3, 1, 6, 7);  // 7`